# How to combine results of two tables when constraint key of one table has few null values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having two tables one is accomodation and one is hotelpaymententry what i want is to combine both the tables without repeating same enquiry_id. below are my tables and query what i tried and its result:
 Table Accomodation

```
Enquiry_Id             Checkin      CheckOut    hotelname              Amount
RH - 26/02/2014 - 10 2014-03-18 2014-03-19  Spice Routes Houseboats     15500
RH - 04/03/2014 - 1  2014-03-19 2014-03-20  Spice Routes Houseboats     9000
RH - 04/03/2014 - 2  2014-03-17 2014-03-18  Spice Routes Houseboats     24000
RH - 05/03/2014 - 6  2014-04-04 2014-04-05  Spice Routes Houseboats     9000
RH - 10/03/2014 - 3  2014-06-17 2014-06-18  Spice Routes Houseboats     33000
```

Table HotelPyamentEntry

```
![enter image description here][1]

 Hotel                   EnquiryId         Checkin    CheckOUt   Totalamount  paynow  dateofpayment 

Spice Routes Houseboats     NULL             NULL       NULL        NULL        5000    2014-12-09
Spice Routes Houseboats     NULL             NULL       NULL        NULL        6000    2014-12-10
Spice Routes Houseboats RH - 10/03/2014 - 3  2014-06-17 2014-06-18  33000      15000    2014-12-08
```

i tried join n union both for the result but inner join returns only common records and left & right join multiplies the records and return 5*3 records and union returns both tables records repeating the enquiry_id RH - 10/03/2014 - 3 means total 8 records. what i want is record from both tables but if enquiryid matches in both tables record appears once and if record is unique in its own table it appears a=in output table. help is badly needed. thanks to all for help in advance.

[image]

Comment: use Union instead of union all..

Comment: Can you post the query you are trying with union and the screenshot of result you are getting?

Comment: sry 4 late reply below is my query using union : select h.Hotel_Name,h.Enquiry_Id,h.CheckIn_Date,h.Checkout_date,h.Client_Name,h.TotalAmount,h.Balance_Amount,h.Pay_Now from HotelPayment_EntryFull h 
where h.Hotel_Name = 'Spice Routes Houseboats' 
union
select a.Hotel_Name,a.Enquiry_Id,a.Ckeck_In,a.check_Out,place,Total_Amount,Total_Amount,Total_Amount from Accomodation a 
where a.Hotel_Name = 'Spice Routes Houseboats' and i am posting screenshot of result in my question part plz check there for the result of this query

Answer (score 0):

```
  select Enquiry_Id,Checkin,CheckOut,hotelname,Amount from Table Accomodation
    union //union doesn't take redundant data
    select Enquiry_Id,Checkin,CheckOut,hotelname,Amount from Table HotelPyamentEntry
```

Comment: thx 4 reply bt i already tried union but its giving repeat query that i mentioned in my question as we increase the fields in query results is diffrent that what we want

Answer (score 0):

To get all records from `accomodation` and matching records from `HotelPyamentEntry` you can write as:

```
SELECT A.Enquiry_Id  
,A.Checkin 
,A.CheckOut 
,A.hotelname 
,A.Amount
,H.paynow
,H.dateofpayment
FROM @Accomodation A 
outer apply
(
SELECT hotel 
,Enquiry_Id  
,Checkin 
,CheckOut 
,Totalamount 
,paynow 
,dateofpayment 
FROM @HotelPyamentEntry HP
WHERE HP.Enquiry_Id = A.Enquiry_Id )AS H
```

and to get records from both the tables you can do a `FULL join` as

```
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(A.Enquiry_Id  ,H.Enquiry_Id)AS Enquiry_Id
,ISNULL(A.Checkin ,H.Checkin)AS Checkin
,ISNULL(A.CheckOut ,H.CheckOut)AS CheckOut
,ISNULL(A.hotelname ,H.hotel)AS hotelname
,ISNULL(A.Amount,H.Totalamount)AS Amount
,H.paynow
,H.dateofpayment
FROM @Accomodation A
FULL JOIN @HotelPyamentEntry H ON A.Enquiry_Id= H.Enquiry_Id
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/GRMAT13950)</kbd>

Comment: in this query on those record will show where enquiry_id matches but in my hotelpayment table i have null enquiry_id's too and i have to combine those records as well can u mow modify your query.

Comment: the second query should serve the purpose.. have a look at demo please and let me the cases where it's still breaking..

Comment: i tried both of the queries but none of the above give the result as you mentioned in your demo. 1st query and 2nd one result the same 5 common records not the null values if i write where a.hotel_name = 'Spice Routes Houseboats' and 2nd query result 7 records as i your demo bt hotel names are diffrent then 'Spice Routes Houseboats' and enquiry_id is RH - 10/03/2014 - 3 plz help me what to do now

Comment: add `a.hotel_name = 'Spice Routes Houseboats' ` in ON clause of join like `ON A.Enquiry_Id= H.Enquiry_Id and A.hotel_name = 'Spice Routes Houseboats' ` in second query

Answer (score 0):

> one often struck when tables are not properly normalize.
>
> Best solution would be to normalize your table with proper
>   relationship .
>
> It is not a case of Union or join or distinct .

See I will try something like this,

```
;With CTE As
(
SELECT  A.Enquiry_Id  AS Enquiry_Id
,A.Checkin AS Checkin
,A.CheckOut CheckOut
,A.hotelname  hotelname
,Amount AS Amount
,0 paynow
,0 dateofpayment
FROM @Accomodation A
UNION all
SELECT H.Enquiry_Id 
,H.Checkin
,H.CheckOut
,H.hotelname
,H.Totalamount
,H.paynow
,H.dateofpayment


FROM @HotelPyamentEntry H 
)
-- analyze this and check which rows you want and which which rows tyou want to eliminate and why.
--then accordsingly put ranking function with partition by and order

select * 
ROW_NUMBER(partition by order by )rownum 
from CTE
```